# Setting ItemTemplate in code behind doesn't refresh display

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox which displays more or less data depending on the level of details that users choose. The ListBox has a dynamic `ItemsSource` set in XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
```

and its default `ItemTemplate` is set using

```
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FewDetails}"
```

in code behind I use

```
MyListBox.ItemTemplate = this.Resources["LotsOfDetails"] as DataTemplate
```

but the list box doesn't refresh.

The only way I've found to make this work is to use a `CollectionViewSource` as my ItemsSource, and to manually refresh the view using `View.Refresh()`.

Any ideas why the straightforward solution doesn't work?

Comment: I Think you should use ObservableCollection instad of list for silvarlightbase

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not using a list here...

Comment: Observablecollection and generic list are different collection and observablecollection has no need to refresh in UI

Comment: Yes, but there are no changes happening in the collection here. I'd like to change the `ItemsTemplate`, bu the items remain the same...